# Set environment variable to > 'graterthan' windows 7 batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How to set Environment variable greater than symbol (>) in batch scripting in windows 7?

This is my script

```
set cmd=dir
set simb=>
set log=c:\Test\grater
```

%cmd% %simb% %log%

Output on cmd is:

> C:\Test>test.bat
>
> C:\Test>set cmd=dir The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>
> C:\Test>set simb=>
>
> C:\Test>

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

escape the `>` with double quotes:

```
set "simb=>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a caret to escape the 'greater than' symbol:

```
set simb=^>
```

If you need to display the greater than symbol, you have to escape both a caret `^` and the `>`:

```
set simb=^^^>
```

or with double quotes:

```
set "simb=^>"
```